Bitcoin wallet generation with P2TR
I am a newbie in bitcoin development and I just started it with bitcoinj library for Java.
I can get the code snippet to generate bitcoin wallet and legacy address.
Timestamp createdAt = Timestamp.valueOf(LocalDateTime.now());
DeterministicSeed seed = new DeterministicSeed(entropy, "", createdAt.getTime()); 
Wallet btcWallet = Wallet.fromSeed(netParams, seed, Script.ScriptType.P2PKH);
Address receiveAddress = btcWallet.currentReceiveAddress();
String bitcoinAddress = receiveAddress.toString();

This works well for P2PKH but I want latest type - P2TR. I just changed that parameter but it throw exception. I could not get any help from googling.
Any help would be great for me.
Thanks in advance.

As far as I know, BitcoinJ does not support (receiving to) taproot addresses yet.

@PieterWuille Ah, I got it. Then what is the latest version that bitcoinj support?

There isn't really a "versioning" of things regarding that, just features that may or may not be supported. I don't follow BitcoinJ development, but according to https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Bech32_adoption, receiving to P2WPKH and P2WSH addresses is supported.

@PieterWuille Thanks a lot.
